# JavaScript test if number variable is a number

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I’m loading a JSON file a reading the values into an array using a for loop

I’m concerned that sometimes the JSON file might become corrupted ie the values Im reading in might become ASCII letters ie 1t3 where the value should of been 123

Is there a test case where you could say if values[a]  does not equal a number then set it to “   “ or blank

Thanks, 
Ben

Comment: An answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric

Comment: This is not something that you should be concerned with. Detecting and correcting errors is the responsibility of the network layer (ex: TCP, etc.) or the file system.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the parseInt() function and check if it returns an integer or NaN. You can check out information on it on [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) or the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

However, in my opinion, it would be better to use regular expressions. If you read the w3schools examples for parseInt(), they show that "0x10" is read as 16.

For a regular expression, try the following:

```js
function isNumber(n) {
  // Added checking for period (in the case of floats)
  var validFloat = function () {
    if (n.match(/[\.][0-9]/) === null || n.match(/[^0-9]/).length !== 1) {
      return false;
    } return true;
      
  };
  return n.match(/[^0-9]/) === null ? true : validFloat();
}

// Example Tests for Code Snippet
console.log(isNumber("993"));
console.log(isNumber("0t1"));
console.log(isNumber("02-0"));
console.log(isNumber("0291"));
console.log(isNumber("0x16"));
console.log(isNumber("8.97"));
```

The MDN Web Docs have a super helpful page on [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: Problematic for floats.`console.log(isNumber("1.5"));`

Comment: You're right, the code should also check that there is one and only one period. Thanks! I totally forgot about floats.

Comment: I updated the code so it checks for a float if there's a special character